# AppEngine return 4 bytes of data

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to return 4 bytes of data from AppEngine (Python).

In some cases I want to return a), in some cases b)

a) 393217 = 0x60001

b) 393218 = 0x60002

The trouble is, If I just write out the base10 number to the output stream like this:

```
class MyClass(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, option):
        self.response.out.write(393217)
```

It returns 6 bytes of data, which is correct if 393217 was interpreted as a string. But I want to return just 4 bytes 0x00060001

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: I was originally returning JSON, I was returning approximately 25 bytes, I figured I could just encode all of the data I wanted to send back in a single 32-bit integer, which is only 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems If I do this:

```
"00600001".decode("hex")
```

I get the 4 bytes I'm after.